# Backup and Restore SQL Server VLDB

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, vldb

We are planning to configure AlwaysOn on SQL Server 2016 (Windows 2016).This is Azure Machine

The DB size is around 15TB. Which is the best method to take backup from Primary and restore in Secondary Replica?

If i follow Backup and restore method definately it will take minimum 40+ hrs for backup and another 40+ hrs for restore, in our environment.

Please suggest. We are testing this in QA, based on this we will plan for PROD.

Comment: What's your criteria for "the best"? Storage snapshots or split mirrors are frequently used to backup large databases.

Comment: Have you looked at "direct seeding"?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2016/05/02/sql-server-2016-alwayson-availability-group-enhancements-initial-data-synchronization-without-database-and-log-backup/